# Why don't I have Deploy actions available in IIS 7 Manager?

Tags: iis-7.5, deployment

I'm currently investigating options to script automated deployment of an ASP.NET web app.  Using MSBuild I can create a package and import it manually or by script into a server running IIS 7.

However, after reading instructions, such as [Vishal Joshi's blog](http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/07/web-deploy-parameterization-in-action.html) about WebDeploy, I'm finding I don't have the Deploy options available on IIS to try out.  I have a Win2008R2 server with IIS 7.5 and have installed the Management Service (WMSvc) component.

I don't see the Deploy section shown in Vishal's screenshot:
[image]

What do I need to install or change to give me import and export?  I need to also do this by command line to import with setParameters.xml for parameter evaluation.

Comment: I installed Web Deploy 3.5 on an IIS 7.5 in Windows 2008R2, but the management options aren't showing up in IIS Manager. I did the same thing on Windows 2012 with IIS 8, and they showed up fine. Are there other steps involved besides installing the link in the accepted answer?

Comment: Just as a side note to this there is some bug where they sometimes don't show up.   If you install them on multiple machines they don't always show up....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/421/installing-web-deploy/

Download and install here - http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy

Comment: Thanks, that was the missing link.  Just that none of the docs come out and say (clearly) that Web Deploy provides that functionality.

Answer (score 7):

i have windows 10.  Even with Web Deploy 3.6, i didn't have the import/export application options in iis.  To correct this, I installed web deployment tool 2.1 from the web platform installer.

Answer (score 2):

For me it turned out the the standard installation did not include the IIS Deployment Handler. The Deploy actions became available after adding these and restarting IIS Manag.er

[image: Web Deploy installer UI]

Comment: In my case I had to uninstall Web Deploy 3.6 and reinstall to make this work.